# Casting generic parameter to subclass

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

Please look at the code bellow:

```
public class BaseClass
{
}

public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
}

public class QueryClass
{
    public TBaseClass[] QueryBase<TBaseClass>() where TBaseClass : BaseClass
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public TSubClass[] QuerySub<TSubClass>() where TSubClass : SubClass
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public TClass[] Query<TClass>() where TClass : BaseClass
    {
        if (typeof(TClass).IsSubclassOf(typeof(SubClass)))
        {
            return QuerySub<TClass>(); // there is error The type 'TClass' must be convertible to SubClass
        }

        return QueryBase<TClass>();
    }
}
```

The question is how to implement Query method. If it is possible..

Comment: Please show your real code. It is invalid in several places apart from the one you mentioned. `public TClass[] QuerySub<TSubClass>() where TClass : SubClass` and `public TClass[] QueryBase<TBaseClass>() where TClass : BaseClass`: `TClass` is undefined. `public void Query<TClass>() where TClass : BaseClass`: return type `void` although the method contains return statements.

Comment: You don't declare TClass generic paramaters on QueryBase methods.
It shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Yeah, it was skeatch. Fixed.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with that construct? You can't cast a generic parameter as it is not an instance.

Comment: I want one generic method to have two filtering behaviours depending on base class.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is doing something like this:

```
public class Animal { }
public class Dog : Animal { }

public void HandleAnimal<T>() where T : Animal
{

}
public void HandleDog<T>() where T : Dog
{

}
```

When you have a reference to `Animal` in this case, there is no way of knowing what `typeof` animal it is. Even if the method returns true, in the context of your code it is still always an `Animal` and you can't handle a `dog` when all you know is that the type is an `animal`. If you were handling instances of objects inside the method you could potentially start casting or instansiating the `subclass` if you know that it is a subclass and then pass that through.

Comment: What I can do if I don't want to write if (animal is Dog) HandleDog(animal as Dog); else HandleAnimal(animal);

Comment: @lazyberezovsky It was a typo haha ;)

Comment: @Jekas Not a lot if your only handling `Types` as Daniel mentioned in his comments, if however your going to be doing passing instances of `TClass` like so: `public void<T>(T obj) where T : Something` you will be able to handle those instances based on their types.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with reflection.

```
        if (typeof(TClass).IsSubclassOf(typeof(SubClass)))
        {
            var method = typeof(QueryClass).GetMethod("QuerySub").MakeGenericMethod(typeof (TClass));

            return (TClass[]) method.Invoke(this, new object[0]);
        }
```

Comment: Why are you passing object args to a method which takes no argument? You should be able to put `null` in there.

Comment: Just checking incase your method was actually taking an argument that I could've done something with earlier :P - other than that, nice solution didn't think of reflection.